# Rails gracefully handle timed out sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using rails 4, ruby 2.

I've set a timeout time of 30 minutes for my cookie session in the rails config.  The problem is if I go to a form, let the session timeout, and then submit the form, I get this `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error.

How do I gracefully handle this error in rails? Say, redirect to login screen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At your `ApplicationController`:

```
rescue_from ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken do 
  redirect_to some_path
end
```